# Why android always kills my app after three different processes?

Tags: android, service

I have written an app using background service, which is launching on specify time. I'm using WakeLocker (CPU only) and for the time I use Handler with delay. During the tests on HTC everything works fine but on Samsung Galaxy S2 everything is weird. Base functionality doesn't work and if service is already active and user run three different apps (not after one, not after two, always after three!!!) My activity is being restarted and doesn't see running service... Why???

Comment: You should put some log first.

Comment: what kind of LOG do you need?

Comment: Could you put up some code, maybe there could be some sort of resource that isn't being cleaned up properly?